# How to create relationships in according to date order in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, relationship, graph-databases

I have many nodes and zero relationships. How can I create relationships that join the same person following date order? (the picture represents the situation I would like to obtain)
[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzN6P.png)

Comment: Please don't YELL. Please avoid thanks, please etc. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have apoc, this is would be my approach.

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WITH p order by p.date
WITH p.name as personName, collect(p) as personList
WITH apoc.coll.pairsMin(personList) as pairs
UNWIND pairs as pair
WITH pair[0] as p0, pair[1] as p1
MERGE (p0)-[:SAME_PERSON]->(p1)
```

Comment: Sadly with this method it doesn't recognize all the same persons. it seems to work but there are some nodes that are not connected to anyone and there are also different connected components that indicate the same person. In my dataset, I have that a person is identified by name and surname. I simply added p.lastname next to personName in the with the condition. I tried with a CSV file composed by 1000 rows

Comment: How can you tell that different connected components indicate the same person?

Comment: That is the correct way to do it. I wonder if you have some extra spaces in the CSV that are causing you trouble. Does replacing the third line in the query with something like this work?
`WITH trim(p.lastname) as lastname, trim(p.firstname) as firstname, collect(p) as personList`

Comment: still have the same problem. It works for the 95% of the dataset, but there is some outlier. However I think I can give you the right answer

Comment: Good luck in solving the last 5%. I think you are on the right track.